# Adding Intel Fortran to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use Intel Fortran on Visual Studios 2015.

Things I tried:

1.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-fortran-compiler-17.0-for-windows-parallel-studio-xe-2017

It says:
"In the New Project window, select a project type under Intel(R) Visual Fortran."
I have the prerequisite VS 2015 Community.

2.https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-fortran-compilers-for-windows-integration-into-microsoft-visual-studio-2015

Says to enable:
Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015
I enabled this on VS.

3.["How to install Intel Fortran Compiler for Ms Visual Studio Community 2017?"](https://superuser.com/q/1197852/860358) on this site says to install Intel Parallel Studio.  After doing this, it seems completely unrelated.

After all this, there still is no option under New Projects in VS: Intel(R) Visual Fortran.
How can I create an intel fortran project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After various attempts including installing the 2017 edition and other online searching, I realize why the instructions on these sites were invalid.

Free student editions of Visual Studios do not include Intel Fortran.
To compile fortran, apparently it is either necessary to use a free compiler not with Visual Studios (MinGW, etc), or pay for a non-student version.

Comment: I am not sure what “student edition” is exactly but the community edition of VS should work.  “For full functionality within Visual Studio, including debugging and development, Visual Studio* Community Edition or higher is required.”  The only “free” edition I am aware of is the community edition